# Google Maps grey screen in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have a function to show a google map:

```
function initMapSA(lat, ln) {

    var myLatLng = { lat: lat, lng: ln };
    var opt = {
       center: myLatLng,
       zoom: 15,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       streetViewControl: false
    };

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas_agent'), opt);
    var markerSa = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng,
         map: map2,
         title: 'Hello World!'
    });

}
```

In `#modal-body` I add `<div id="map_canvas_agent"></div>`

I trigger it via a form button click event:

```
$(".sa-location").click(function () {
     var id = $("#ServiceAgent").val(); //combobox value
     $.get("@Url.Action("GetServiceAgentLocation")", { id: id }, function (data) {
         initMapSA(data.Lat, data.Ln);//Initialize google maps
     }, "json");

});
```

The Goole Map is showing but it is just a grey screen rather than an actual map. How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you show us your html / css code as well ? Sometimes it's the max-height property on img that could cause that.

Comment: If possible, can you please create and share your fiddle here.

Comment: @VincentG - just add min-height:300px

Comment: Have you seen this [link](http://www.interslicedesigns.com/blog/twitter-bootstrap-and-google-maps-doesnt-load-grey-screen/) before? It mentions that ***Bootstrap by default sets a rule*** -- `img { max-width: 100%; }` ***So that images don’t overflow their spans. However if you’re embedding Google Maps in your site, it messes up the zoom controls. You can override that with `max-width: none`, easiest way is to make a rule overriding it for just your map’s parent node***.

Answer (score 0):

Force trigger a resize on the map:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```